# How to re-trigger an HTTP call on parameter change?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service method that fires an HTTP call with parameters passed to it. It works, no trouble there.

What I need to do is have my component re-trigger that call when those parameters change. I'm still getting to grips with observables and RxJS in general, so I'm not sure how to do this. I've got the parameters set up as a Subject, with a new object of those parameters being sent to it on each change. So, if I subscribe to the parameters Subject, how do I best re-fire the HTTP call? Resubscribing on each change seems enormously messy.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use `switchMap()`? With it you do not need to handle any of the subscriptions, until your component is torn down.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    //remember to inject your service properly
    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.parametersChange$
            .asObservable()
            .switchMap(params => this.http.get(`/do/something/with/your/{params}`))
            .subscribe(x => console.log(x))//handle your http
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there, just subscribe to your Subject, and each time you get a new value from it, fire an Http call.

Also you're right, as you need to subscribe to actually trigger your http call, you'll be forced to re-subscribe every time. To optimize, you can keep track of your http call subscription and unsubscribe to it every time your parameters change so you don't track an "old" request.

Something like that :

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    parametersChange$: Subject;
    httpSubscription: Subscription;

    ngOnInit () {
       this.parametersChange$.subscribe(params => {
           if (this.httpSubscription) {
              this.httpSubscription.unsubscribe();
           }
           this.httpSubscription = this.http.get(...).subscribe(// do your stuff);
       });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: So re-subscribe on every parameter change? Angular's HTTP client only actually makes the requests on a subscription, so I'd end up with a ton of subscriptions which seems odd, but I'm certainly not knowledgeable enough to know if that's right or wrong.

Comment: Yeah, as you said, you need to subscribe to your observable to actually trigger your http call, so you will have to re-subscribe every time. I updated my answer with an example of how to handle it without having a ton of subscriptions

Comment: I don't think you should subsribe within a subscribe. 

Answer (score -1):

Are you expecting a stream of answers from the http call?  If not, it might be cleaner to do something like:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    parametersChange$: Subject;
    httpResult

    ngOnInit () {
       this.parametersChange$.subscribe(async params => {
           this.httpResult = await this.http.get(params).toPromise();
       });
    }
}
```